# Altium: Unable to select component that ended up outside of the schematic sheet area

Tags: altium

So I use "Smart paste" to create array of copies, then I selected the whole block and moved it to the side. Altium correctly moved the block and placed some components outside the sheet area. No error message was given.

Now I am unable to move these components back into the sheet and am unable to select them by clicking on them. What do I do? Please see the components in that are outside the sheet in the diagram below:

[image]

Comment: try `select all` shortcut

Comment: Could also use Edit->Select->Outside Area

Comment: @Lars Hankeln, so this is a feature and not a bug in Altium designer?

Comment: @jsotola, there are a lot of other things as well, on the other side of the schematic. If I use select all and move this one to the left, the other things will then fall outside the schematic area.

Comment: do select all ... drag everything to left until problem circuit is on the sheet ... select the problem circuit and drag it left a bit ... do select all and drag everything to the right

Comment: This is a joke is what it is.  I've had all kinds of problems with Altium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Temporarily make the sheet size larger, move parts, then make sheet size smaller.

Comment: Yes that worked, I guess this is the only way around this bug? The sheet size must be changed from the properties panel of the sheet and not the preferences.